# Recover systemd from uninterruptible state

Tags: centos, systemd

Recently ssh-ing into a CentOs8 VM become extremly slow. I checked the top command which showes this:

```
    load average: 30.09, 30.13, 30.09
    Tasks: 403 total,   1 running, 364 sleeping,   0 stopped,  38 zombie
    %Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.9 id,  0.0 wa,  1.4 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
    MiB Mem :  15853.6 total,   5322.0 free,   8791.9 used,   1739.7 buff/cache
    MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   6052.8 avail Mem

     PID  USER     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
       1 root      20   0  245460   8192   4132 D   0.0   0.1 662:05.04 systemd
      43 root      39  19       0      0      0 D   0.0   0.0  15:06.70 khugepaged
      56 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.0   0.0  68:38.87 kswapd0
   34809 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 sh
   41031 101       20   0   34248  25884      4 D   0.0   0.2   0:00.62 nginx
   41309 root      20   0   93260   6740   5904 D   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 systemd-user-ru
   44308 root      20   0   57184   3760   3340 D   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 ps    
    ...etc
```

Some other commands get into 'D' state immediatly once I use it like ps,pgrep.
So if I type 'ps aux' the terminal becomes unresponsive then logging back from an other terminal I can see that the new 'ps' command is added to the 'D' processes.

```
All of the ps,grep D state process's and  and systemd's stack trace:    
[<0>] __access_remote_vm+0x5a/0x2d0
[<0>] proc_pid_cmdline_read+0x1a6/0x350
[<0>] vfs_read+0x91/0x140
[<0>] ksys_read+0x4f/0xb0
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x1b0
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x65/0xca
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff

khugepaged:
[<0>] collapse_huge_page+0x11f/0xdf0
[<0>] khugepaged+0xb4f/0x1140
[<0>] kthread+0x112/0x130
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff

kswapd0:
[<0>] rpc_wait_bit_killable+0x1e/0x90 [sunrpc]
[<0>] _nfs4_proc_delegreturn+0x22e/0x330 [nfsv4]
[<0>] nfs4_proc_delegreturn+0x7c/0x130 [nfsv4]
[<0>] nfs_do_return_delegation+0x33/0x50 [nfsv4]
[<0>] nfs4_evict_inode+0x25/0x70 [nfsv4]
[<0>] evict+0xd2/0x1a0
[<0>] dispose_list+0x48/0x60
[<0>] prune_icache_sb+0x52/0x70
[<0>] super_cache_scan+0x123/0x1a0
[<0>] do_shrink_slab+0x118/0x270
[<0>] shrink_slab+0x187/0x2e0
[<0>] shrink_node+0xe4/0x440
[<0>] balance_pgdat+0x1e2/0x340
[<0>] kswapd+0x21a/0x400
[<0>] kthread+0x112/0x130
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
[<0>] prealloc_shrinker+0x6d/0x110

systemd-user-ru:
[<0>] sget_userns+0x2c0/0x4b0
[<0>] mount_nodev+0x2a/0xa0
[<0>] mount_fs+0x3b/0x167
[<0>] vfs_kern_mount.part.35+0x54/0x120
[<0>] do_mount+0x1fc/0xc80
[<0>] ksys_mount+0xb6/0xd0
[<0>] __x64_sys_mount+0x21/0x30
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x1b0
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x65/0xca
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

What else should I look for? Is their a way to recover from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the only possible recovery is a reboot — preferably via SysRq, so you get a chance to flush file systems and unmount those that aren't stuck. Do *not* `sudo reboot`, as it might hang while the system is waiting for the last process to finish (which it'll never do).

But sometimes it's still possible to gradually back out of this state. In your case, I'd start with systemd itself. If you can't recover it, a reboot is the only option. So try:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reexec
```

This will fork a new copy of systemd, hand it the current state, and terminate the current copy of systemd — hopefully taking all the problems with it. This command might fail, either by becoming uninterruptible like `ps` does, or just failing to connect to the existing systemd instance.

If you get systemd back, you can try a similar trick on other daemons: try to restart them. Some [might be killable even in the "uninterruptible" state](https://lwn.net/Articles/288056/), try `kill -9`.

The stacktraces mention filesystems and NFS in particular. NFS is notorious for this kind of problems, so consider not using it for vital things like the root partition.